# Constant in time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I understand that if time complexity of an algorithm is c * O(N), where c is a constant, we can ignore c and complexity is same as O(N).

Can we do same if its O(N) + c.

I have this doubt because for an algorithm which involves sorting and scanning(like finding unique elements in an array), various texts state its complexity to be N *log(N).

If we take both steps, then its:

Sorting: N*log(N)
Scanning: N

So total time is N * (log(N) + 1).

Comment: The notation c.O(N) has no meaning. You probably mean O(c.N), which is indeed equivalent to O(N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that [the definition of big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) says `f(x) = O(g(x))` (as x goes to ∞) if there is an `M > 0` and an `x0` such that for `x > x0`, `|f(x)| ≤ M g(x)`.

Let's take `f(x) = x * (log(x) + 1)` (your “total time”) and `g(x) = x * log(x)` and see if we can find suitable `M` and `x0`.

```
|x * (log(x) + 1)| ≤ M * x * log(x)
```

`x * (log(x) + 1) ≥ 0` for all `x > 1`, so we'll require `x0 ≥ 1`. That lets us drop the absolute value operation:

```
x * (log(x) + 1) ≤ M * x * log(x)
```

Since we're requiring `x > 1`, it's safe to divide out the `x` from both sides:

```
log(x) + 1 ≤ M * log(x)
```

Assuming we're using the natural logarithm, we know `1 = log(e)` (where `e` is the base of natural logarithms, 2.71828...), so let's substitute that in.

```
log(x) + log(e) ≤ M * log(x)
```

And `log(x) + log(e) = log(x * e)`, so let's substitute that in:

```
log(x * e) ≤ M * log(x)
```

And `M * log(x) = log(x^M)` (that's `x` raised to the `M` power):

```
                  M
log(x * e) ≤ log(x )
```

Now apply the exponentiation function to both sides to eliminate the logs:

```
                    M
 log(x * e).   log(x )
e           ≤ e

         M
x * e ≤ x
```

If we take `x = 2` and `M = 3`, then the inequality holds:

```
                      3
2 * e = 5.43656... ≤ 2 = 8
```

So, substituting `x0 = 1` and `M = 3` into the original inequality, we have

```
|x * (log(x) + 1)| ≤ 3 * x * log(x)   for x > 1
```

From this we can conclude that `x * (log(x) + 1) = O(x * log(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering O(f(N) + g(N)), if one of the functions grows slower (the ratio tends to zero), you can ignore it.

E.g. O(N²+N.Log(N)) = O(N²) and O(1+1/N)=O(1).

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do same if its O(N) + c?

Yes we can.

As N grows larger, `N*log(N)` is greater than or equal to `N`. We can transform the original `N*log(N) + N` as follows:

[image]

In fact, we can make the rule more general. E.g.,
[image]

For a polynomial, Big O is determined by the term with highest/fastest order, and we may disregard lower-order terms of the polynomial. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties) has some explanation.